# facebook login with codeigniter error URL blocked

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I have a code from a tutorial to login with facebook. Now when i go to the login with facebook, it says error with

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

I already configure my appsettings with the settings in this screenshot:
[image]

setup from Oauth:
[image]

i am using codeigniter with these codes :

```
<?php
include(APPPATH.'libraries/facebook/src/facebook.php');

class Connect extends Facebook {

    public $user = null;
    public $user_id = null;
    public $fb = false;
    public $fbSession = false;
    public $appkey = 0;

    public function Connect() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->config->load('facebook',TRUE);
        $config = $ci->config->item('facebook');
//      echo $config['appId'];
        parent::__construct($config);

        $this->user_id = $this->getUser();
        $me = null;
        if($this->user_id){
            try {
                $me = $this->api('/me');
                $this->user = $me;

            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and with this in my controller:

```
public function facebook_request(){


            $data = array (
                'redirect_uri' => base_url('authentication/handle_facebook_login'),
                'scope' => 'email'
            );

            var_dump($data);

            $this->load->library('connect');
            redirect($this->connect->getLoginUrl($data));
    }

    public function handle_facebook_login() {

            $this->load->library('connect');
            if($this->connect->user) {
                print_r($this->connect->user);
            } else {

            }
    }
```

Comment: is localhost a valid supported domain?

Comment: i think so sir. because i dont have any domain yet @charlietfl

Comment: I mean for the Oauth, not for your use

Comment: Hello sir, i edited my question. and screenshot my Oauth there @charlietfl

Comment: add platform on settings-basic?

Comment: hello sir this problem is already solved. can you please help me in this problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354913/cannot-login-with-facebook-in-codeigniter-going-to-false-in-if-condition